# How can I send an email with multiple field entries using Mail::send

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am currently working on my final year project for University. I am currently able to send an email showing a message using 'msg' => $request->message. I was wondering if there is a way that I can send an email that has multiple field entries for example something like this:

```
    'msg' => $request->message, $request->ornamentation
```

I am not sure how to write this, the above does not work. Thanks.

I have attached my controller file below along with my html.

ContactMessageController

```
        <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Mail;


    use Illuminate\Http\Request;



    class ContactMessageController extends Controller
    {

        public function create(){

            return view('contact');
        }

        public function store(Request $request)

        {

    $this->validate($request,[    

        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required'

        ]);

        Mail::send('emails.contact-message', [

            'msg' => $request->message

        ], function ($mail) use($request) {

            $mail->from($request->email, $request->name);

            $mail->to('flannery-n@ulster.ac.uk')->subject('Contact message');

        });

        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message', 'Thank you for your message');

        }
    }
```

Contact.blade.php

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>

        .invalid-feedback {

            display: block;
        }

    </style>
    <title> Contact </title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <h1> Feedback Form </h1>

        <div class="row">       
            <div class="col-md-6">

                @if (Session::has('flash_message'))

                    <div class="alert alert-success">{{ Session::get('flash_message') }}</div>

                @endif

                <form method="post" action="{{route('contact.store')}}">

                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label> Full Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
                        @if ($errors->has('name'))
                        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback"> {{ $errors->first('name') }}</small>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>  Email: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback"> {{ $errors->first('email') }}</small>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label> Technical Ability: </label>
                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter comments here" style="width: 600px;                                height: 100px;"></textarea> 
                        @if ($errors->has('message'))
                        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback"> {{ $errors->first('message') }}</small>
                        @endif      
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label> Ornamentation: </label>
                        <textarea name="ornamentation" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter comments here" style="width:                             600px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
                        @if ($errors->has('message'))
                        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback"> {{ $errors->first('message') }}</small>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label> Speed: </label>
                        <textarea name="speed" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter comments here" style="width: 600px;                              height: 100px;"></textarea>
                        @if ($errors->has('message'))
                        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback"> {{ $errors->first('message') }}</small>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label> Control: </label>
                        <textarea name="control" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter comments here" style="width: 600px;                            height: 100px;"></textarea>
                        @if ($errors->has('message'))
                        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback"> {{ $errors->first('message') }}</small>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label> Additional comments: </label>
                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter comments here" style="width: 600px;                            height: 100px;"></textarea>
                        @if ($errors->has('message'))
                        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback"> {{ $errors->first('message') }}</small>
                        @endif
                    </div>


                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>


    </form>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>      

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're outputting the `$msg` variable contents to your email template doing something like this:

```
{{ $msg }}
```

So, in that case, you could add the additional request attributes the same way.

First, make sure they're being passed to your template:

```
Mail::send('emails.contact-message', [

    'msg' => $request->message,
    'ornamentation' => $request->ornamentation,

    // And any other attribute you want to pass along

], function ($mail) use ($request) {
    $mail->from($request->email, $request->name);
    $mail->to('flannery-n@ulster.ac.uk')->subject('Contact message');
});
```

Then, you can output the attributes to your template, the same way you do with `$msg`:

```
{{ $ornamentation }}
```

Just to be clear, the variables available in the template have the same name as the keys of the passed array. If you had, for instance, an array such as:

```
[
    'foo' => $request->message,
    'bar' => $request->ornamentation,
]
```

The variables in the template would be:

```
{{ $foo }}
```

and

```
{{ $bar }}
```